# Docker desktop on Mac doesn't bring up nginx home page with Kubernetes

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes

I am using k8s on Docker desktop on Mac. I have applied the below yaml file and the deployment got success. But when I access "localhost:8888", I get page not found and can't see nginx default homepage. (images attached)

````
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-nginx
        image: nginx
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-nginx-np
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: my-nginx-np
  ports:
  - port: 8888
    targetPort: 80```

[enter image description here][1]


[enter image description here][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/edbG9.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak6UZ.png
````

Answer (score 0):

Your service is not pointing to the Nginx deployment (you are using the wrong selectors). Try to use the following service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-nginx-np
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: my-nginx
  ports:
  - port: 8888
    targetPort: 80
```

Comment: Thanks. It works now after changing the selector to "my-nginx". Anyways, it works only with "http://localhost:30569" and not with "http://localhost:8888" . Is that expected behavior ?

Comment: yes, NodePorts are in the 30000-32767 range by default, which means a NodePort is unlikely to match a service’s intended port.